# What's the difference between decimal and percentage line-height

Tags: css

(This question originally referenced w3c schools, I've corrected that reference)

[According to w3c](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-line-height) the CSS `line-height` value can be set as follows:

> `<number>`    The used value of the property is this number multiplied by the element's font size. Negative values are illegal. The computed value is the same as the specified value.
>
> `<percentage>`  The computed value of the property is this percentage multiplied by the element's computed font size

So `line height = font-size × number` or `line height = font-size × percentage ÷ 100%`, which should be the same.

And line-height is inherited.

However, I've noticed that nested elements that increase the font size result in quite different line heights, as can be seen here:

[image: screenshot]

Column C (blue) is what I would have expected.

[See jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bkunsr0h/1/).

Column A is, if you pardon this mashup of css syntax for sake of succinctness:

```
 div {line-height:140%;} > div > div «content»
```

Column B is:

```
 div {line-height:140%;} > div > div {line-height:140%} «content»
```

Column C is:

```
 div {line-height:140%;} > div > div {line-height:1.40} «content»
```

### Half way to understanding

So it looks like column A, the line height is being *calculated as a length (e.g. pixels) and set* on the outer div's `font-size`. This calculated, **length value** is then inherited, which is why it looks squashed up when the font size subsequently increases.

The specs for both refer to the value being multiplied by the font size. So this refers to the font size of the element on which line-height is set, not the font size of the element that inherits the line-height.

So that goes half way to explaining. But columns B, C only differ in specifying 1.4 or 140%, which are the same. Surely?!

I would expect the behaviour of the blue Column C for at least Column B and C. (Although I think it's pretty weird that it's not Column A, too, but at least I understand that.)

I've checked and Firefox and Chromium do the same thing.

**Can you explain?**

Comment: W3Schools is **NOT** the W3C. They are a cleverly advertised 3rd party site, often with a lot of errors and non-factual claims. It's best to refer to the [actual W3C spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-line-height) instead.

Comment: @Marc B: A percentage line height is relative to the element's own font size, not its parent's, unless its font size is exactly 1em.

Comment: @BoltClock: doh, right...

Comment: @artfulrobot also note that it's effectively useless to use `rem` (in lieu of `em`) on the hierarchically-highest element, as there are no elements between it and the root element that require jumping over.

Comment: @TylerH thanks for pointing out dumb wc3schools error, I've updated the question, but it still stands, I think.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Percentage line heights are computed first based on the font size for the given element. This computed value is *then* inherited pre-baked by descendants. The computed value of a decimal line height on the other hand is *that decimal value* (this is what is meant by "specified value"); what you end up seeing is the *used* value, which is "computed" on each descendant based on its own font size *after* it has been inherited. In CSS, [it is computed values that are inherited](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#inheritance), not used values.

Let's start with the container:

```
.container {
    font-size:1rem;
    line-height:140%;
}
```

The container has a computed font size of 1rem, and a computed line height of 1.4rem.

1. This computed line height is then inherited by column A. Column A has a font size of 1.2rem, and a line height of 1.4rem.

   The *same* line height is then inherited by the child of column A, so its font size computes to 1.44rem (based on column A's) and its line height remains as 1.4rem.
2. You override the line height of column B such that it gets its own `line-height:140%` declaration. This percentage is calculated based on the font size of column B. That makes 140% of 1.2rem, not of 1rem, resulting in a line height of 1.68rem.

   This value is then inherited by the child of column B. Its font size computes to 1.44rem and its line height 1.68rem.
3. You override the line height of column C with a `line-height:1.40` declaration. While the font size and line height of column C are calculated in the same way as those of column B, what is *inherited* by its child is *not* 1.4 × 1.2rem = 1.68rem; it is 1.4 (a ratio, or a raw percentage if you will, but not a length).

   So the child of column C has a computed line height of 1.4, as inherited from column C. This value is then used in calculating the child's line height based on its own font size. Therefore its *used* line height is 1.4 × 1.44rem = 2.016rem.

Eric Meyer has a great [article](http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2006/02/08/unitless-line-heights) on decimal vs percentage line heights. Mine just happens to be a slightly more convoluted explanation, but the principles are the same.

Comment: Thanks for such a clear answer, and for linking to Eric Meyer's article which was also very helpful.