# is line-height:1 equivalent to 100%?

Tags: css

Please take a look at the following snippets first:

```css
body {
  line-height: 1;
}
```

```html
<h1>
  Hello <br> world
</h1>
```

```css
body {
  line-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<h1>
  Hello <br> world
</h1>
```

The upper one uses `line-height: 1;`, while the lower one uses `line-height: 100%;`. I thought they must be identical, and [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height) seems to agree with me:

> `<number>`
>
> The used value is this unitless `<number>` multiplied by the element's
>   font size. The computed value is the same as the specified `<number>`.
>   In most cases **this is the preferred** way to set line-height with no
>   unexpected results in case of inheritance.
>
> `<percentage>`
>
> Relative to the font size of the element itself. The computed value is
>   this percentage multiplied by the element's computed font size.
>   **Percentage** and **em** values may have unexpected results, see "Notes" section.

and in the "Notes" section:

> It is often more convenient to set `line-height` by using the `font`
>   shortcut as stated in the "Examples" section above.

However, actually, they are different!

My question is: Why are they different, and should I prefer `<number>` as suggested by MDN?

---

I'm using Safari Version 10.0.1 (12602.2.14.0.7).

Comment: Just saw the edited version of your question, the section below the **Notes** is explaining the same point as in my answer but I guess it could've been explained better and the explanation could have been outside code block (and not as comment).

Comment: @Harry Yes, that would be very nice! Maybe you can edit this section on MDN to benefit more people?

Comment: I've made an update to the answer to explain based on recent version of the specs (I was referring to an old one earlier). In essence the answers are the same but the revised wordings picked up from the specs would help you understand things better :)

Comment: @Harry Great! I wish I could upvote your answer twice :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The real reason is that the way they work is different and it can be understood by having a look at the [W3C Specs for line-height](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#line-height) and [inheritance](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#inheritance). The below is what the spec for line-height says about the unitless value (`<number>`) and the percentage value.

> **<number>** - The used value of the property is this number multiplied by the element's font size. Negative values are illegal. The ***computed value is the same as the specified value***.
>
> **<percentage>** - The ***computed value of the property is this percentage multiplied by the element's computed font size***. Negative values are illegal

As [BoltClock points out in his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40317159/is-line-height1-equivalent-to-100/40317292#comment67907494_40317292) (correctly, as usual), inheritance always works the same way and it is ***always the computed value that gets inherited***.  The confusion with wordings was because I was referring to an older version of the spec whereas the new one is very clear and is using the right words.

When unitless value (number) is specified, the specified value for `line-height` is the number which is also the computed value. So, `h1` (child) inherits the number which is 1 but it still needs to resolve this number into an actual `line-height` that can be *used*. So, the used value is calculated based on specs by multiplying the *inherited factor* with the `h1` element's font-size (which is 2em = 32px) and sets `line-height` as `32px`.

For the percentage, the computed value for `line-height` at `body` is 100% of body's font-size (which is `16px`)  and so is equal to `16px`. Now since this `16px` is the computed value, the `h1` child *inherits* this value and uses it as-is because there is no need for further resolutions.

This is the reason why there is a difference between the two snippets as in one the line height for the `h1` is 16px and in another it is 32px.

---

If we set the `line-height: 100%` directly at `h1` then we can see that the outputs match because now the `h1` calculates its own line-height as 100% of 2em (or 32px) which is same as 1 * its font-size.

```css
h1 {
  line-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<h1>
  Hello <br> world
</h1>
```

Comment: Does this inheritance rule apply to all CSS properties, or it only applies to `line-height`?

Comment: Inheritance works for a lot of CSS properties but generally the pattern is like they inherit the computed values (or resultant values). I haven't seen many properties which work the same way as line-height with unitless value (infact, I haven't seen any).

Comment: Inheritance works the same for all properties. It's the computed value that's different in the case of line-height.

Comment: The confusing wording is a result of quoting CSS1. Don't do that. CSS1 has a lot of inconsistent wording with current specs because a lot of that behavior was not very well defined at the time.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @BoltClock. I generally don't even visit the old specs (unless it is to search for history), so must've accidentally followed the wrong link from MDN. Let me check the new one but I still think this property is behaving a bit differently. Maybe reading the new one would make me change my mind :D

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32994911/whats-the-difference-between-decimal-and-and-percentage-line-height/32995898#32995898 "Percentage line heights are computed first based on the font size for the given element. This computed value is *then* inherited pre-baked by descendants. The computed value of a decimal line height on the other hand is *that decimal value* (this is what is meant by "specified value"); what you end up seeing is the *used* value, which is "computed" on each descendant based on its own font size *after* it has been inherited."

Comment: In short, the specified value is computed differently when it's a <number> than when it's a <percentage>. How the computed value is then inherited is the same for all properties.

Comment: Hmm yeah was reading this one - https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#computed-value and your point is correct. So when we set a unitless value as line-height, that number becomes the computed value (and used values are found out only when document is laid out) - interesting. So in a way I think what the answer says about inheriting the factor and then calculating the value is correct. Just the terminologies used are wrong. Can I say that? @BoltClock